# SetWindowsHookEx to monitor Windows open and close

Tags: windows, hook, setwindowshookex

I took this example code from [here](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/83707-setwindowshookex-example.html) that hooks a function to intercept keyboard events, and it works:

```
#include <Windows.h>

// variable to store the HANDLE to the hook. Don't declare it anywhere else then globally
// or you will get problems since every function uses this variable.
HHOOK _hook;

// This struct contains the data received by the hook callback. As you see in the callback function
// it contains the thing you will need: vkCode = virtual key code.
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

// This is the callback function. Consider it the event that is raised when, in this case, 
// a key is pressed.
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // the action is valid: HC_ACTION.
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // lParam is the pointer to the struct containing the data needed, so cast and assign it to kdbStruct.
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            // a key (non-system) is pressed.
            if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_F1)
            {
                // F1 is pressed!
                MessageBox(NULL, "F1 is pressed!", "key pressed", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
        }
    }

    // call the next hook in the hook chain. This is nessecary or your hook chain will break and the hook stops
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{
    // Set the hook and set it to use the callback function above
    // WH_KEYBOARD_LL means it will set a low level keyboard hook. More information about it at MSDN.
    // The last 2 parameters are NULL, 0 because the callback function is in the same thread and window as the
    // function that sets and releases the hook. If you create a hack you will not need the callback function 
    // in another place then your own code file anyway. Read more about it at MSDN.
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to install hook!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}

void main()
{
    // Set the hook
    SetHook();

    // Don't mind this, it is a meaningless loop to keep a console application running.
    // I used this to test the keyboard hook functionality. If you want to test it, keep it in ;)
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
}
```

I am trying to make the similar code works for `WH_GETMESSAGE` to intercept `WH_CREATE` and `WH_DESTROY` messages, but it didn't work:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>

HHOOK _hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK  GetMsgProc(_In_ int nCode,    _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Enter hook\n";
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // the action is valid: HC_ACTION.
        std::cout << "HC_ACtION\n";
        if (wParam != PM_REMOVE) return NULL;
        MSG m = *((MSG*)lParam);
        std::cout << "Message received\n";
        TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(m.hwnd, 0, Buffer, MAX_PATH))
        {
            // At this point, buffer contains the full path to the executable
            MessageBox(NULL, Buffer, L"key pressed", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        else
        {
            // You better call GetLastError() here
        }
        //CloseHandle(Hand);
    }

    // call the next hook in the hook chain. This is nessecary or your hook chain will break and the hook stops
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{       
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, NULL, 0)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to install hook!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}

void main()
{
    // Set the hook
    SetHook();

    // Don't mind this, it is a meaningless loop to keep a console application running.
    // I used this to test the keyboard hook functionality. If you want to test it, keep it in ;)
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }
}
```

MSDN specifies to use the function `GetMsgProc` with a predefined signature, but I don't see it does anything.

Comment: Surely you saw SetWindowsHookEx fail?  It is a very ugly hook type to get right, it requires a DLL to be injected.  So the 3rd argument cannot be NULL.  Especially painful on a 64-bit OS since you need two distinct injectors.  There are better ways to do this, look at UI automation and SetWinEventHook().

Comment: But the first example did work even without compiling a separated DLL. Can I set a global hook with SetWinEventhook()? What I want to do is that when I receive a message, I check if it is from a window with a certain name, and if it is, do something. Is it possible with UI Automation?